# Post Photo Facebook iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to upload a photo to Facebook. I read a lot of tutorials and examples and still can't get it to work. Many times I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in this line:

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                 andParams:photosParams
                             andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                               andDelegate:self];
```

Other times nothing appears. I want  the user to login only when they click on "share image" in Facebook. Thats why I didn't put the delegate in the `appDelegate`.  Below is my code:

```
if (_facebook != nil)  {
        [self fbDidLogin];
    }  

    _publishedImage = img;
    _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"235694579858240" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) 
    {
        _facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        _facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![_facebook isSessionValid])
    {
        NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"offline_access", @"publish_stream", @"publish_actions", @"photo_upload", nil];

        [_facebook authorize:permissions];
    }

    UIImage *imgSource = img;
    NSString *strMessage = @"This is the photo caption";
    NSMutableDictionary* photosParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         imgSource,@"source",
                                         strMessage,@"message",
                                         nil];

    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                     andParams:photosParams
                                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                   andDelegate:self];
```

My ViewController has these delegates:

```
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, FBSessionDelegate, FBDialogDelegate, FBRequestDelegate>
```

Edit: Are there any plugins to share photos easily in Facebook, G+, and everything else easily?

Comment: Hi All,

Thought I'd share with you here, I just posted a tutorial over at my blog on how to upload photo and post a status update using the latest Facebook SDK. There is also a sample project to be downloaded.

Check it out here:
http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-upload-photo-and-update-status.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the graph why don't you try:

```
      if ([fbAppDelegate.facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                                                                       @"http://hd.ipad-wallpapers.fr/thumbs/wooden_apple_logo_4-t1.jpg // but could also use UIImage", @"picture", nil]; // you don't



    [fbAppDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

}

// this is what I do .....
```

Comment: Hi men, Thanks. But still crashing. Could you share me all the code wuth the init?

Comment: I fixit. I was addingan static library that i build with the script Facebook gives. But my project its ARC and i get troubles. I get the source of Facebook and refactor to ARC modify everything i need and I add it again to my project and it works :) Thanks